# To use the Room database, How to correctly add the Maven Repository and the necessary dependencies in build.gradle in android studio (flamingo)?

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, android-room

I'm making a simple patient registration app using java, and I'm starting to learn and use the room database. I am tremendously confused on how to add the dependencies in gradle and the maven repository. Every tutorial I see shows something different. And the documentation on android developer just confused me even more. I'm using the latest version of studio (flamingo) and I think the gradle version is 8.

For example, most tutorials on youtube and the internet say that I should go to gradle script -> build.gradle(project) and add this:

```
allprojects{
    repositories{
Google()
jcenter()
maven {url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}
```

But in the google documentation it says to add this:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {

repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
     repositories {
         Google()
}
```

Some other tutorials put it like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        Google()
        mavenCentral()
}
```

In my build.gradle(project) there is nothing there. Just a few lines with plugins and id's:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
     id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.0' apply false
     id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.0' apply false
}
```

---

1 - Where should I put the code anyway? And which of these codes??

2 - And in build.gradle(app), which dependencies should I put there and where in the code??

As you can see this is extremely confusing for a beginner. I really appreciate any help from you, and sorry if the post was too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use settings.gradle. Inside settings.gradle you'll find file contents that look like this

```
`pluginManagement {
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
            gradlePluginPortal()
        }
    }
    dependencyResolutionManagement {
        repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }
    rootProject.name = "Sync"
    include ':app'`
```

You can then add the maven code in this block of code under mavenCentral

```
`dependencyResolutionManagement {
        repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }`
```